# How to convert spoken time to datetime (quarter to, quarter pass..)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert a string containing time spoken by a human to a time object.
This string can including idioms such as "Quarter to two, five past ten", etc.

I do something similar for dates using [dates-fns](https://date-fns.org/) (javascript).

I haven't found a library that does the same for 'spoken' hours. What would be the best approach to implement it? Just a brute force dictionary?

I am using node js, but I will be open to use solution in other languages if any exists.

Comment: Be aware that it needs to be language-specific. “Half three” in UK English means 3:30, but “halb drei” in German means 2:30 — half an hour before three, not half an hour after.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for natural language processing, which is no small feat. You may want to look into [node-nlp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-nlp)

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Recognizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/recognizers-text-date-time) sounds like the best fit for your usecase - they've got a node.js package available. As others have mentioned, your input is not well-formatted (ie) not in any kind of predetermined format like `MMDDYYss` and is also culture dependent, so you'll need an NLP solution rather than the more common packages like moment.js that do deterministic parsing.

Comment: Wow, looks like a great project, sort of what I need, thanks for the share

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [node-numbered](https://github.com/blakeembrey/node-numbered) package and see if this is what you are looking for.